# How notify user when my application is not running in qt?

Tags: qt, notifications, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a qt quick 2 application that I run it in android.Now I want to show message to my users ,For example I want to send a get Request to my server to find out "Is this user has any message from another user or not?" and if has new message show a notification to my user.This should be run when my application is not runnng.

But I didn't see any Class that i can do this in qt?

How can I Do this?

Comment: How do you want to notify a user? Dialog, updating some text, toast or whatever?

Comment: @folibis I want to show notification when application is not running.

Comment: You have to clarify the question. What does your _not running_ mean? How can you work with a server from an application that doesn't run? What will handle the response and show a notification? What is your _real_ target? Just to avoid XY problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt for Android](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android.html) lists what you can do with Qt. [Qt Android Extras](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html)  includes classes that wrap the most important functions of few Android package methods, but is not intended to provide out of the box methods for everything in Android.

You can write Java Classes to implement detailed or specialized Android functions, those then can easily be implemented with Qt using the rich Android Extras *JNI* APIs.

In Qt Examples, [Qt Notifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html), serves very similar or same functionality you asking for.

You can run Android services (long running apps hiding user interface) ,  by [Creating Android Services](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-services.html#) And [QAndroidService Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidservice.html)

Comment: in Qt Notifier .the notification is possible when the applicaiton is running.

Comment: I want to khow how can i show notification when my application is not runing

Comment: Then your question should be _How to run Android service with messages_ , and that's possible.